# Private AKS is not able to find the path of my local files to do a deployment through Helm

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm currently trying to deploy my helm charts through my private aks cluster. However, I'm unable to do anything since it can't find the path of my local directory.

This is the command that I'm running:

```
az aks command invoke \
--resource-group aharo-aks-appgateway01 \
--name aharo-aks02 \
--command "helm install haro ./haro_files_helm_chart"
```

This is the error message that I'm getting

```
command started at 2023-01-06 22:49:46+00:00, finished at 2023-01-06 22:49:46+00:00 with exitcode=1
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: path "./haro_files_helm_chart" not found
```

To prove that this type of commands can work, I tried one from the Microsoft Documentation:

```
az aks command invoke \   
--resource-group aharo-aks-appgateway01 \
--name aharo-aks02 \  
--command "helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami && helm repo update && helm install my-release bitnami/nginx"
```

What else can I do to find the path of my directory? Do you know if I could be missing any configuration on my cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing the helm install command to the AKS VMs, the VMs(nodes) will be looking for `./haro_files_helm_chart` in their filesystem not the machine that is running the command, hence the path not found error.

In the example you shared, the node is installing a helm chart that it is downloading first.

To resolve the issue, you should attach the directory of the helm chart with the `az aks command invoke` as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/command-invoke#use-command-invoke-to-run-commands-with-an-attached-file-or-directory). Below is the part you need:

> You can also attach all files in the current directory. For example:

```
az aks command invoke \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --command "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml configmap.yaml -n default" \
  --file .
```

For example, I created a chart called "test-chart" and installed it using `helm create test-chart`. The chart would be created in the current directory im in:

```
$ls
test-chart
```

Then run the same command shared above and just change the command (without changing the directory):

```
az aks command invoke \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --command "helm install test-chart-override-name test-chart" \
  --file .
```

Comment: Yes, I tried as well but is not working still. The result is that it can't find the path

Comment: Also, how is going to know that it will have to install using helm instead of using kubectl?

Comment: edited the answer to address your questions

Comment: I found the answer. Inside of the command flag, I don't have to target the directory or any files there. I just need to have the following command "helm install [name_of_project] ." & this will get everything deployed

Comment: That's the same thing :) you are just passing the dir as ".", as you are inside the charts directory

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is the following:

```
az aks command invoke \
--resource-group aharo-aks-appgateway01 \
--name aharo-aks02 \
--command "helm install haro . "
```

Anoother workaround is uploading your helm charts to your container registry & then, you will have to download them and install them directly like the example from microsoft:

```
az aks command invoke \   
--resource-group aharo-aks-appgateway01 \
--name aharo-aks02 \  
--command "helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami && helm repo update && helm install my-release bitnami/nginx"
```